# How to bypass ASP.NET Core culture-sensitive conversion of form data?

Tags: asp.net-core, localization, asp.net-core-localization

I am using ASP.NET Core [Localization middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization/select-language-culture?view=aspnetcore-7.0) in my application to pick up the **AspNetCore.Culture** cookie value.

```
services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
{
    options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture(myDefaultCulture, myDefaultCulture);
    options.SupportedCultures = options.SupportedUICultures = mySupportedCultures;

    options.RequestCultureProviders.Clear();
    options.RequestCultureProviders.Add(new CookieRequestCultureProvider());
});
```

Now, I have an action which picks up browser geo-location values submitted from my client form:

```
<div>
    <input id="lat" name="lat" value="">
    <input id="long" name="long" value="">
</div>
```

Looking at my http request, the values are something like **27.67807948515076** and **-109.11917758267799**.
Since my action is taking two **double** values, it works fine when the request's cookie is en-us. But if the **AspNetCore.Culture** cookie is set to **es-es**, my action is getting value like **2767807948515076** and **-10911917758267799**.  Seems like it is because [ASP.NET Core will let form data to go through culture-sensitive conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#globalization-behavior-of-model-binding-route-data-and-query-strings) by design.

What is the best practice to handle this case? Should my client detect the cookie setting and send data in different format? Or should I try to bypass the culture-sensitive conversion on server side? I guess I should not since it is by design for a reason. But if I need to, how to achieve that?

I tried to use string types in my action signature and try to parse the value to double. It works. But I feel this is a common case that should have a better solution that manually handle this in code logic.

Comment: Can this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66318456/localized-query-string-parameters-in-asp-core) help you solve this issue?

Comment: Not really.  It seems to be doing the opposite - letting query string parameters to go through culture-sensitive model binding. Here I am looking for a way to let form data NOT to go through culture-sensitive model binding, if recommended.